# How to secure variable send through URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using PHP and CI framework, I want to send variable through URL but I want it to be somewhat encrypted.

For example i want to send variable named id:

> www.trythis.com/site?id=123

I want it to be

> www.trythis.com/site?id=VkxSiOW31S

The encrypted text is just an example.
How can I do that? or is there CI function that can do this?

**Note:** I already try base64_encode but it somehow can't be used in CI due to its special characters such as ==.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter has [Encryption Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html). You can use that class to encrypt and decrypt. To configure follow the steps

1. **Setting your Key**

   `$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";`
2. **Initializing the Class**

   `$this->load->library('encrypt');`

To encode use

```
$id = '123';
$encrypted_id = $this->encrypt->encode($id);
//$url = 'www.trythis.com/site?id=' . $encrypted_id;
```

And to decode

```
//$encrypted_id = $_GET['id'];
$decrypted_id = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this class for the same purpose:

```
class Cypher
{

    public $encrypted;
    public $decrypted;

    public function __construct($_value) {

        $this->encrypted = $this->encrypting($_value);
        $this->decrypted = $this->decrypting($_value);

    }

    private function encrypting($_value) {

        $key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $utf8 = utf8_encode($_value);
        $cipher = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $utf8, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $cipher = $iv.$cipher;
        $base64 = base64_encode($_value);

        return $base64;

    }

    private function decrypting($_value) {

        return base64_decode($_value);

    }

}
```

---

Let's try your example:

```
$cypher = new Cypher('123');

header("location: www.trythis.com/site?id=".$cypher -> encrypted);
```

On www.trythis.com/site page:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? new Cypher($_GET['id']) : "";

echo $id -> decrypted;
```